# Search for more than one element in a list in Cassandra

Tags: search, cassandra, cql3

I'm learning how the data model works in Cassandra, what things you can do and what not, etc.

I've seen you can have collections and I'm wondering if you can search for the elements inside the collection. I've seen that you can look for one element with contains, but if you want to look for more than one you need to add more filters, is there any way to do this better? is it a bad practice?. 
This my table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE data (
  group_id int,
  user timeuuid,
  friends LIST<VARCHAR>,
  PRIMARY KEY (group_id, user)
);
```

And this what I know i can use to look for more than one item in the list:

`SELECT * FROM groups where friends contains 'bob' and friends contains 'Pete' ALLOW FILTERING;`

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Secondary indexes are generally not recommended for performance reasons.

Generally, in Cassandra, Query based modelling should be followed.

So,

That would mean another table:

```
 CREATE TABLE friend_group_relation (
  friend VARCHAR,
  group_id int,
  <user if needed>
  PRIMARY KEY ((friend), group_id)
  );
```

Now you can use either IN query (**not** recommended) or async queries (**strongly** recommended, very fast response) on this table.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow 2 different approaches

1. Pure cassandra: use a secondary index on your collection type as defined here [documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/collection_type_r.html)
2. You may also be able to use Solr and create a query against solr to retrieve your entries. Although this may look like a more complicated solution because it will require to use an extra tool it will avoid using secondary indexes on Cassandra. Secondary indexes on Cassandra are really expensive and based on on your schema definition may impact your performances.